# How to count element in list PYTHON?

Tags: python

I want to realize in python a function that help me:
I have a list with number

```
a= [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Every time I find 0, I need to count it and know his position but, when there are consecutive 0 entries, it count as one, for example:

```
Position start 5, Position end 8, Count 1
Position start 12, Position end 12, Count 2
Position start 14, Position end 14, Count 3
Position start 26, Position end 31, Count 4
```

How I can achieve that? I'm having problem getting consecutive element and problem with saving position start and end of the consecutive element.

Comment: @buran thanks, i have edited the post, in particular Im having problem getting consecutive element and problem with saving position start and end of the consecutive element.

Comment: When you're looping, just test if `a[i] == a[i-1]` to tell if they're consecutive.

Comment: You could also make use of `itertools.groupby()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looping through once, checking if the last element was zero should do it:

```
a= [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
last_was_0=False
zero_clusters=[]

for i in range(len(a)):
    b=a[i]
    if b==0:
        if last_was_0:
            zero_clusters[-1][-1]+=1
        else:
            zero_clusters.append([i, i])
    last_was_0 = b==0

for i in range(len(zero_clusters)):
    print(f'Position start {zero_clusters[i][0]}, Position end {zero_clusters[i][1]}, Count {i+1}')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this work fine, and If in case i want to use two list, for example b and c can I check if both are 0?
So if b==0 and c==0
It count the zeros
Its possible?

Comment: if i use another list with the same index i it don't work, how i can do?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the beginning and end indices of the sub-sequences as follows:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
begin = [i for i, el in enumerate(a) if (i == 0 and el == 0) or (el == 0 and a[i - 1] != 0)]
end = [i - 1 for i, el in enumerate(a) if i == len(a) or (el == 1 and a[i - 1] == 0)]
```

which yield

```
[5, 12, 14, 16, 28, 36, 38, 40]
[8, 12, 14, 16, 33, 36, 38, 40]
```

You can print the result as

```
for begin_idx, end_idx, count in zip(begin, end, range(len(end))):
    print(f"Position start {begin_idx}, Position end {end_idx}, Count {count}")
```

---

Otherwise a for loop as others suggested:

```
count = 1
for i, el in enumerate(a):
    if el == 0 and (i == 0 or a[i-1] == 1):
        begin_idx = i
    elif i > 0 and (el == 1 and a[i -1] == 0) or i == len(a):
        print(f"Position start {begin_idx}, Position end {i-1}, Count {count}")
        count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

curr=0
cnt=0
          
for k,g in groupby(a):
    n = len(list(g))
    if k==0:
        cnt+=1
        print(curr, cnt)
        curr+=n
  
5 1
12 2
14 3
16 4
28 5
36 6
38 7
40 8
```